# Como mostrar um Messagebox ao selecionar um item no combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

Gostaria de sabe como faço pra implementar em meu `combobox` um `Messagebox` ao selecionar um item da lista?

Exemplo:

Lista do combo:

1. Junior
2. Maria
3. José

Ao selecionar Maria, aparecer uma caixa de mensagem informando: 
Você selecionou "Maria", botão OK.

Comment: Jose edite sua pergunta e inclua o código com o que já tentou.

Answer (score 5):

O `ComboBox` tem um evento `SelectedIndexChanged`, basta você implementar ele e adicionar um `MessageBox` para mostrar a mensagem desejada.

Algo do tipo

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Você selecionou o item {(sender as ComboBox).Text}");
}
```

Para adicionar o evento ao seu componente. No modo *design* do seu formulário, selecione o componente, clique com o direito sobre ele e após em *Properties*. Na janela de *Properties* clique no icone de *Events* (um raio), na categoria *Behavior*, de dois cliques sobre o evento que desejas criar para o componente, nesse caso o evento `SelectedIndexChanged`